# postgresql - "group_id" column in query once row value changes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following schema and sample data (sample):

```
with t
as
(
    select 1::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 100::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to
        union
    select 2::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 100::int buyers ,200::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to
        union
    select 3::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 500::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to
        union
    select 4::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 100::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.03::numeric price_to
        union
    select 5::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 300::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.03::numeric price_to
        union
    select 6::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 100::int buyers ,200::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to
        union
    select 7::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 500::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to
    order by 1
)
select * 
from t
```

I'm trying to assign a "group id" to rows that have same from_price and to_price so I will be able to perform calculations on it's intervals and other fields I omitted from the sample.

**Clarification:**

If the price values re-appear in the next rows, it should have a new group id, so i cannot aggregate just by the price.

the price change is what i care about. there are two price changes, creating 3 groups (even that the price in the third group is the same as the first). each price change should start a groupid.

I.e. desired output (with group_id column):

```
with t
as
(
    select 1::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 100::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to ,1::int group_id
        union
    select 2::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 100::int buyers ,200::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to, 1::int group_id
        union
    select 3::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 500::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to, 1::int group_id
        union
    select 4::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 100::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.03::numeric price_to, 2::int group_id
        union
    select 5::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 300::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.03::numeric price_to, 2::int group_id
        union
    select 6::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 100::int buyers ,200::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to, 3::int group_id
        union
    select 7::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 500::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to, 3::int group_id
    order by 1
)
select * 
from t
```

I tried using row_number() and dense_rank() functions with partition over the price columns but still couldn't get what I wanted.

I can create a script in python or other scripting language to "mark" those for me,
but was interested to know if there's an SQL way to increment a group id when one of the price values change.

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A little tip: the `select ... union` can be simplified to `values (1, 10.01, 100, 100, 10.02), (2, 10.01, ...), ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this helps a bit: first i calculate the price_change and then sum over the price_changeflag
using a window function lag() -> look 1 row before and compare. If you also need to have a look at price_from, extend the where/when clause

```
with t
as
(
    select 1::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 100::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to ,1::int group_id
        union
    select 2::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 100::int buyers ,200::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to, 1::int group_id
        union
    select 3::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 500::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to, 1::int group_id
        union
    select 4::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 100::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.03::numeric price_to, 2::int group_id
        union
    select 5::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 300::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.03::numeric price_to, 2::int group_id
        union
    select 6::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 100::int buyers ,200::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to, 3::int group_id
        union
    select 7::int id , 10.01::numeric price_from , 500::int buyers ,100::int sellers ,  10.02::numeric price_to, 3::int group_id
    order by 1
), 
t2 as
( 
select
*,
lag(price_to,1,0::numeric) over (ORDER by id) as price_before,
case when lag(price_to,1,0::numeric) over (ORDER by id) <> price_to
then 1
else 0 end  as pricechange
 from t
)

select
*,
sum(pricechange) over (ORDER BY id RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as group_id
 from
t2
```

Comment: Dude, this is gold! i did not know about the lag function! modified the expression a bit to consider pricefrom as change factor as well and works like a charm. cheers ;)